# Equation of an unknown Curve?!?

Tags: calculus

What is this function in the graph below ? How can we write the equation of this graph from the graph ? Please Help.

I have found in answers that this graph has an equation 
f(t)=(A+Bt)e^​−Ct

Can anybody tell me how to derive this equation from this graph ? What are A, B and C in this graph ? How this is shown as an exponential function in the equation ? Whats the way to find this equation. Please answer i shall be very grateful to you.[image: GRAPH]

Comment: All I can tell you is that the moment I saw this I was immediately reminded of the plot of the integrand of the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). The latter part of the graphic definitely reminds us of the plot of $e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 1):

First off the graph looks linear for small $t$ and drops off exponentially for large $t$ thus we know that the form you give could fit the job (though you have try many fits normally to get something nice).

$$
f(t) = (A+Bt)\mathrm{e}^{-Ct} 
$$
first parameter
$$
f(0) = (A+ B\cdot 0)\mathrm{e}^{-C\cdot 0} = A =\text{intercept}\\
$$
from your graph $A=1$
then we look at the maximum
$$
f' = B \mathrm{e}^{-Ct}  -C(A+Bt)\mathrm{e}^{-Ct}  = \mathrm{e}^{-Ct} \left[1 + -AC-BCt\right]
$$
remember that the exponential term is not zero in a finite value of $t$ thus we can conclude the maximum (peak) is located when
$$
1 + -AC-BCt_{\max} = 0 
$$
to get the decay I would take values where the exponential is sufficiently large and take the log plot to determine the gradient of that point to get $C$ and then get $B$.

Alternatively you have eliminated one parameter so you can use two points on the graph with the full equation and try and obtain what $B$ and $C$ are.