# How to write the equation of this graph in the given figure?

Tags: calculus

[image]

By looking at the graph we come to know that whether the graph is linear or exponential or quadratic etc. If the graph is a straight line then we write the equation of the straight line for the graph and same is the case with other graphs i guess.

So what is this graph ? May i have not been able to identify it . Can anybody tell me what is this function and how can we write the equation of this graph from the graph?

Comment: What level class are you in?  Are you allowed to use things like derivatives, or do you have to work with just basic notions?

Comment: i am in college i know what is is derivative. please tell me how can i write the equation of such type of curves from the graph.

Comment: @Raymond Manzoni

Comment: @GregoryGrant ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of 
[equation-of-an-unknown-curve](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217313/equation-of-an-unknown-curve)

Answer (score 0):

Curves of the family $f(x)=(kx+1)\mathrm e^{-lx}$ look very much like that. They have a maximum at $\dfrac 1l-\dfrac 1k$ (this value is positive if  $k>l$, and the value of this maximum is $\,\dfrac kl\mathrm e^{-lx}$.

See two curves of the family:

[image]

Comment: Thanx alot @bernard . actually bernard i am confused. how you came to know that this graphs equation is of the form f(x) = (kx+1)e^lx ? is there any general procedure to write the equation of such curves ? i know about the function transformation. but how a curve will look like and how we will write its equation if graph is "zig zag" means with no definite shape.

Comment: It just happens that function of type $kx\mathrm e^{-lx}$ are standard exercises that I've taught a number of times. The polynomial factor must have degree $1$ to have only one maximum. So these are the simplest functions with such a general look. I'm afraid there is no general procedure.

Comment: thank you @bernard really. so you were familiar with that function that is why you are able to write the equation of the function. suppose there is a graph that you see first time in your life then tell me how you will be able to write the equation of that graph when there is no general procedure for that. is there any way to do that ? actually i saw this graph for the first time also and get confused so i ask that.

Comment: Well, if I me a curve that's really new for me, I'd look on sites dedicated to curves, in the hope it commes from a well-known problem, and ask mathematician friends. That's about all I could do.

Comment: thank you @bernard may you have many curves in life. lol. thank you very much.